# ProcessorContext#header() is Empty

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have kafka stream application. Producer is adding header in kafka message before sending it to Kafka Streaming application.

In Kafka streaming app we are using `AbstractProcessor` and `context.forward(null, Optional.of(event));` to forward message to another topic.

But header is getting lossed. I want header to be as it is from input message to output topic.

`ProcessorContext` Interface. `headers()` method says Returns the headers of the current input record but it's empty in my case though I am sending message with header.

```
     * Returns the headers of the current input record; could be null if it is not available
     * @return the headers
     */
    Headers headers();
```

Kafka Stream API Version: 2.3.1

Comment: Where are you calling `context.headers()`. Is it within the processor's `process()`?

Comment: It got resolved. I was calling context.headers() outside og Process method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.headers()` shoud be called with in `process()` if using a Processor or `transform()` if using a Transformer.